# What are these mysterious craters?

Tags: air-travel, identify-this, landmarks, geography, volcanoes

Flying over southern Oregon or northern California, I saw these strange shapes. They look like burial mounds but are much much bigger...

[image: Mysterious craters]

Can anyone tell me what they are?

Comment: They could be the [Jordan Craters](http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/oldroot/volcanoes/volc_images/north_america/jordan_craters.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Volcanic craters, most likely.  The [Cascades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_Range) are mostly volcanic, after all.

You can see some similar-looking volcanoes [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.5727883,-121.2927951,11.77z/data=!5m1!1e4), just east of Lassen *Volcanic* National Park.  And [lots more](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.5779692,-121.6962208,11.02z/data=!5m1!1e4) near *Lava Beds* National Monument.  And [yet more](https://www.google.com/maps/@43.7412644,-121.410649,10.77z/data=!5m1!1e4)...  They are easier to spot in terrain view than satellite.